# Widget is not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, widget, home-page

I am trying to insert a **Catalog Category Link** widget in my *Home Page*. But it is not working. I am sharing the code below.

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" template="category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/9"}}
```

Comment: How is it not working? You get an error? You don't see anything?

Comment: Thanks @Echron for your reply. It is displaying nothing.

Comment: Can you add the property anchor_text:
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" anchor_text="Some text here"  template="category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/9"}}

I guess it needs some text to render